# passenger phusion stopped working after apt-get update/upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger

Well, I am not sure where to start.
We have rails based apps.

We did nothing in our websites. (did not touch ANY config file etc).

Just a regular apt-get update, upgrade.
Suddenly 2 websites are down!
What can be the problem?

This is an ubuntu machine that we are running.

DNS is OK.
We can go to the root page that says: ubuntu... everything is working fine.

We have apache server. Tried to: sudo apachectl restart.

Also, working on AMAZON cloud if it matters (aws.amazon)
Tried to reboot from Amazon. Same result.

Comment: So you've done an apt-get upgrade on your servers while they are running?    (brave man).  Please add some more details of your setup to your question.  How do you normally start the server?  Have you tried doing that?   Are you using apache, nginx, some other http server?

Comment: I'd suggest tailing the Application logs and web server logs, how far does your request get into the system before an error is triggered

Comment: @MaxWilliams updated my question

Comment: @maniacalrobot It seems that nothing gets into the server. App logs are empty. server logs do not show anything as much as I can tell

Comment: Have you tried a deploy, which would (i'd expect, normally) restart everything in sequence?  Anyway as @maniacalrobot says, look in your logs.

Comment: Has the update added/changed any of the vhosts? it could be a default vhost is intercepting all incoming traffic?

Comment: Or you could try to reinstall apache+Passenger. apt-get may have overridden it, an i believe passenger needs to install a special a version of apache for it to work?

Comment: @maniacalrobot - where can I find vhosts?

Comment: I already reinstalled everything

Comment: depending on your versions, vhosts will probably be in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ , You'll then need to ensure they're symlinked to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ . They are resolved in by alphabetical order, so if you managed to get a 000-default vhost, this could be intercepting all incoming traffic

Answer (score 0):

If anything goes wrong, the first thing you should try is to follow the official troubleshooting guide: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/troubleshooting/ruby/